# HTML5/Javascript GeoLocation: Pass data to callback function -or- suspend async call (with promises)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, asynchronous, geolocation

I need to get HTML5/Javascript Geolocations to pass the location data to an ajax call to store in a database.  The problem I ran into was that (1) the Geolocation call is asynchronous and (2) the variable scopes are tripping me up.

There are two approaches I'm considering, but I'm not sure how to get either one working quite right.  Below are the approaches:

Need to pass the `this` value from the `.click` in the code below:

```
jQuery("div#normal .m_action").click(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(storeAction(action), errorAction);
});

function storeAction(action, position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { action: this.id, lat: latitude, long: longitude }
    }).done(function(result) {
        if(result == "error") {
            alert("Error in ajax action.php file");
        } else {
            jQuery(action).removeClass("m_action");
            jQuery(action).html(result);
        }
    }).fail(function(result) {
        alert("There was an error with the ajax call itself")
    });
}
```

Or I can try postponing the ajax call until after the `getCurrentPosition` call completes.  The code below is just a rough estimate of what I'm talking about, though I realize (of course) that it's far from correct:

```
jQuery("div#normal .m_action").click(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(storeAction(this), errorAction).then(function() {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "./checkpoint.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { action: this.id, user: "driver", key: <?php echo "12345"; ?>, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, accuracy: accuracy }
        }).done(function(result) {
                if(result == "error") {
                    alert("The action could not be complete.  If this persists, please contact dispatch directly.");
                } else {
                    jQuery(action).addClass("m_action_complete");
                    jQuery(action).removeClass("m_action");
                    jQuery(action).html(result);
                }
        }).fail(function(result) {
            alert("There was an error, please try again.  If this persists, please contact dispatch directly.")
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `success()` method which is named `storeAction()` is wrong. It should take one parameter which is position. The first example: if you get rid of `action` parameter you should get correct latitude, longitude and accuracy.

Comment: @AntoJurković Yes, but then I cannot look up the clicked function object, here: `jQuery(action).removeClass("m_action");`  I need to be able to do both, and that's where my question lay.

Comment: Did you try to provide `action` using global variable?

Comment: @AntoJurković I knew there was a simple solution, thank you so much!  Re-reading my question I realized just how unclear I made it.  That's what I get for writing it when I was exhausted.  Thank you for the simple fix!  If you'd like to submit it as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getCurrentPosition()` method is defined as:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)
```

where `success` is a callback function that takes a `Position` object as its sole input parameter. Using that object you can get latitude, longitude and accuracy. Parameter `action` can be provided as a global variable.